Prove that $x^6+5x^2+8$ is reducible over Z (integer)?
$attempts:-$
1] I tried to replace $X^2=t$ but nothing click after that .
2] then I tried to replace this polynomial say P(x) by P(x+1) or P(x-1) to apply Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion Theorem but nothing work
3] Then I equate $x^6+5x^2+8$ = ( $ax^2+bx+c$ )( $dx^4+ex^3+fx^2+gx +h$) but nothing happens after equating LHS = RHS .... similar tecqniue also used but get some contradiction type things... however when I doing calculation...I was doing some silky mistake but after checking many times I don't understand where I am doing wrong as such methods must work.
However I think this expression must be irreducible as no method was working.
Is it  really reducible over Integer? If yes then please tell me how you do this? I am trying this question from 2-3 days.

@J.W.Tanner if we put x=+-1, +-2,+-4, +-8 then the above expression will never become zero by rational root Theorem

A sextic polynomial could be linear times quintic, quadratic time quartic, or cubic times cubic. So, one must also consider factorizations of the form $(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(ex^3+fx^2+gx+h)$. The rational roots test (testing $x=\pm1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm8$) easily implies that there are no linear factors.

Also, there is a typo in your factorization, because $c$ appears twice. It should instead be $(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^4+ex^3+fx^2+gx+h)$.

Mathematica returns True for IrreduciblePolynomialQ[x^6 + 5x^2 + 8].  So it is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, hence also in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

@GeoffreyTrang thanks you very much... I have edited it

A note: By injecting into the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$, you can justify that any factorization must have degrees 2 and 4, from $P(x) \geq 8$

$f(x) = x^6 + 5x^2 + 8$ is irreducible. You can ask WolframAlpha to factor the polynomial $\bmod p$ for small primes $p$ (each of these is a finite computation so in principle you could do this yourself by hand). You get
$$f(x) \equiv (x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1)(x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 2) \bmod 3$$
$$f(x) \equiv (x^2 + 2)(x^2 + x + 2)(x^2 + 4x + 2) \bmod 5$$
and this is already enough to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible! This is because if it were reducible it would have to have an irreducible factor of degree $1$, $2$, or $3$, and the first calculation rules out the possibility of degrees $1$ or $2$, while the second calculation rules out the possibility of degree $3$ (since a degree $3$ factor would either remain irreducible or have at least one degree $1$ factor $\bmod 5$).
WolframAlpha will also tell you that $f(x)$ is irreducible $\bmod 29$ although this would be quite a bit more annoying to verify by hand. Instead of doing the $\bmod 5$ computation you can also observe that $f(x)$ has no real roots, meaning its irreducible factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ must be as a product of $3$ irreducible quadratics.

 This argument generalizes. The irreducible factorization of a monic polynomial $f(x) = \prod f_i(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ (equivalently, by Gauss's lemma, over $\mathbb{Q}$) produces a partition $\deg f = \sum \deg f_i$ of the degree of $f$, and the irreducible factorization $\bmod p$ must give a refinement of the partition over $\mathbb{Z}$. So if the only common coarsening of all the $\bmod p$ partitions is the trivial partition $\deg f = \deg f$ then $f$ is irreducible. This method can be used not only to show irreducibility but to compute Galois groups, via the Frobenius density theorem, for irreducible $f$ with $\deg f \le 7$.


Let $f(x) = x^6 + 5x^2 + 8$, and suppose $g(x)$ is an irreducible divisor of $f(x)$. Then $g(-x)$ is also irreducible and divides $f(x)$, since $f(x)$ is even.
Note that either $g(x) = g(-x)$, or $g(x)g(-x)$ divides $f(x)$: If $g(x)g(-x)$ does not divide $f(x)$, then $g(x)$ and $g(-x)$ must be the same irreducible factor of $f(x)$ up to multiplication by a unit, so $g(-x) = (-1)^{\deg g} g(x)$. Moreover, $g(-x) = -g(x)$ is impossible, since that would imply $f(0) = 0$, so we must have $g(x) = g(-x)$.
If $g(x)$ were a cubic, we would have $f(x) = -g(x)g(-x)$, so $f(0) = -g(0)^2$, which is a contradiction since $f(0)$ is positive.
Therefore, if $f$ is reducible, $f$ can be written as a product of at least two even polynomials which are either irreducible or of the form $\pm g(x) g(-x)$ for $g$ irreducible. Since any even polynomial is a polynomial in $x^2$, this would give a proper factorization of $t^3 + 5t + 8$, but we know $t^3 + 5t + 8$ is irreducible since it has no integer roots.

$x^3+5 x + 8$ has one negative root $-\alpha$, and two complex conjugates $\beta$, and $\bar \beta$, so
$$x^3 + 5 x +8 = (x+\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\bar \beta)$$
Let $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ a square root of $\beta$. Then we have
$$x^6 + 5 x^2+8 = (x^2+\alpha)(x^2-\gamma^2)(x^2-\bar \gamma^2) = (x^2+\alpha)\cdot [ (x-\gamma)(x-\bar \gamma)]\cdot [(x+\gamma)(x+\bar \gamma)]$$
the factorization into three irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Note that none of these factors lies in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ( look at the free terms), so we cannot produce from it a factorization into two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$p(x)=x^6+5x^2+8\geq8$ has no real root, so it can not have a linear or cubic factor in its factorization.
If $x^2+ax+b$ is a quadratic factor then $x^2-ax+b$ is also quadratic factor. See arkeet's answer. If $a\neq0$, there is a third quadratic factor which must be in the form $x^2+d$. (If $a=0$, it is already in this form.) But, this is impossible, because the real root of $t^3+5t+8$ is not integer, that is, $d\not\in\Bbb Z.$
